# Need Help on Floating (sticky) Elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

A client has requested that the sidebar on some templates be made sticky. However, the problem is that the sidebars in question would occasionally be too tall to fit within the browser window.

The idea we have is that when the sidebar runs outside of the viewable area, it would scroll as normal, but as soon as the bottom part is visible,  it would stop. It would initiate again, when the user scrolled up.

I can't seem to find any examples of this happening. My google-fu has failed me.

Anybody have any ideas on how this could be implemented? I figure I can use some fairly simple jQuery, but am having difficulty figuring out exactly which hooks to use.

Any tutorials, examples, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want the sidebar attached to the top of the window when the user scrolls upwards, to the bottom when he scrolls downwards and move with the scroll when the direction changes?

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle it like this:

Im assuming your sidebar container has an id of "sidebar"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#sidebar').height() < $(window).height()) {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

Then make a css class called sticky with whatever properties you want for when its not as tall as the screen, eg:

```
.sticky {
   position:fixed;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```

Edit: Use `position:fixed !important;` if the sticky class isnt overriding the css you have set on #sidebar.

Edit again: Sorry, i re-read the question. I would start with the above, and then you will want to bind to the window scroll event and run some tests - try something like this:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(){
    if($('#sidebar').offset().top - $("html").scrollTop() < 0) {
        //the top of the sidebar has scrolled above the top of the viewport
    } else {
        //the top of the sidebar is still below the top of the viewport
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.